# Can we use gmail API in aws lambda python runtime to send mail?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gmail-api, aws-api-gateway

I have Oauth credentials for gmail API, I need to use it in python language in aws lambda,  API [according to documentation need to install some package to use gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) 
how to send mail from my gmail account in aws lambda . if anybody done this before , provide some example code or reference .
I searched lot, i can't find solution

Comment: It sounds somewhat like you are actually trying to ask whether it is possible to "install" dependencies for Lambda functions.

Comment: I am trying to smtp in python lambda, when sending mail it show the security error , because gmail changed some security features, they provide api for send mails through programming.
But there is no proper documentation, searched lot, no solution for my problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to use [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email) and create

```
import boto3
ses_client = boto3.client('ses')

def sendEmail( ses_client, sender, recipients, subject, body ):
    return ses_client.send_email( 
            Source = sender, 
            Destination = { "ToAddresses": recipients },
            Message = { 
             "Subject": { "Data": subject, "Charset": "UTF-8" },
             "Body": { "Text": { "Data": body, "Charset": "UTF-8" } } 
             })
```

in order for this to work you'll have to verify email addresses:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses-procedure.html

Comment: Its good idea , and working.
its useful to send bulk email.
sometimes we don't send any single mail at that time will aws charge for SMTP?

Comment: have a look at https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/ - i believe they'll charge you per usage only

Comment: @ArunKumar did you stick with SES or give a chance to calls to Google API?

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy your endpoints to a separate EC2 instance on AWS, and then send requests for your API from Lambda.

I haven't done this with the Gmail API, but I had to do it for the Office API, which similarly requires the installation of a package.

Comment: I need it for a static website , my website hosted in s3 , API gateway will call my lambda function.

Comment: I need python script to use a gmail api to send mail from aws lambda